# Protocol/algorithms based on a variable-length input PRF

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-function

Are the proofs based on a PRF assumption still valid when using a variable-length input PRF ?

The answer might be obvious, but I have a doubt.

Comment: I think it generally is true but the devil is in the details. Any particular protocol/algorithm you're looking at?